# gcc: decide to which function does a line of code belong to

Tags: c

How can I extract someting similar?
The goal is to determinate easily in which function does one line of code belong to. The goal is to create a similar file:

```
none:   void funct1(void)
funct1: {
funct1:   int i = 0;
funct1:   int j = 0;
funct1:   ....
funct1: }

none:    void functXY(void)
functXY: {
functXY:   int i = 0;
functXY:   int j = 0;
functXY:   ....
functXY: }
```

Do I really need AST for this?
I use gcc compiler with C89 code.

Comment: I would use AWK for this.

Comment: What  AST is standing for?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Abstract Syntax Tree

Comment: Why an "unclear" close vote? It's pretty clear..

Comment: I guess the most straight-forward way would be just to traverse your files for function definitions, and mark each line between the two definitions with the function defined before. It will be complete but not sound. In terms that the code can contain declarations between the functions.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse a C file outside your program, or how to know in which function a line is inside your own program (which could be useful for logging macro, for example)? Provide some more details.

Comment: `int i = 0;` belongs to both functions. There is not enough info to tell you more. For `funct1:   int i = 0;` it's obvious where the line belongs to. So what is the question please?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Then can you explain what this question means? I have no idea what he's trying to do.